# adal javascript windows store app token

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps, adal

I have a javascript windows store app that is authenticathing with AAD via  Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication library. It works against an ASP.NET WebAPI hosted in Azure. It works fine, it prompst the user to login (windows login service), once logged the user can work and is not asked to log in again. The problem I have found is that when the user does not use the app for a time, I´m not sure but I Think is between 20 and 30 minutes, the app gets iddle. It does not respond to user querys. I think comunication with webApi is lost, I'm not sure if the token acquired by the app is expired or Azure itself cuts the connection.

This is how I'm getting the token

```
var authcontext = new aal.AuthenticationContext(audience);
aal.DefaultTokenCache().clear();
return authcontext.acquireTokenAsync(resource, clientID, redirectUri.absoluteUri, "", null).then(function (result) {
     if (aal.AuthenticationStatus.succeeded == result.status) {
         accessToken = result.accessToken;
         return true;
     }
}
```

and the webApi call

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(apiUrl + apiName);
        var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();

        httpClient.defaultRequestHeaders.authorization =
            new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        return httpClient.getAsync(uri).then(function (response) {
            if (response.isSuccessStatusCode == true)
                return response.content.readAsStringAsync().then(function (responseText) {
                    var array = JSON.parse(responseText);
                    return array;
                });
            else
            {
                var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(response, "Error");
                md.showAsync();
            }
        });
```

I`ve tried adding

`<sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="96:00:00" />` and `<cookieHandler persistentSessionLifetime="60.0:0:0" requireSsl="true" />` in the web.config but still getting the error.

I am trying unsuccesfully adding ADAL new releases to the project because I read something about refresh tokens, I'm working on it but don´t find any example for windows store apps.

Any clue about the cause of the problem and how to solve it??

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library version you are using is ancient and not supported. Also, cookies play no part in the api communications.
I recommend switching to the latest stable ADAL. Windows Store sample using ADAL: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WindowsStore

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved my problem, I was saving the token and doing the requests with the saved one, so after a period of time it gets expired and the app gets iddle. I´m triying to update to new library, and withe the same code I´m getting type mismatch error at acquiretokenasync line, is there any change in that method??

Comment: LOTS of changes. Yours was a very early preview.

Comment: Solved the problem, I did the change to the new version and it works. Thanks